# ZeroBrane Studios: How to Compile Entire Project?

Tags: zerobrane

As title says, how do I compile the entire project?

When I click Project -> Compile (or use corresponding shortcut key) it only compiles the currently open file.

I want to compile the entire project. Compiling each file one at a time is cumbersome, and shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [AnalyzeAll](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBranePackage/blob/master/analyzeall.lua) plugin that compiles/analyzes all files in a project. Note that the compilation doesn't produce any compiled files (like `luac` does), it simply checks for Lua syntax errors.

Comment: If you don't mind a followup question, how would I set a shortcut for this function? Based on the documentation and source file, I've tried adding `keymap[ID.analyzeall] = "F8"` (among other things) to user.lua, but it keeps throwing a nil error.

Comment: Try `ID("analyzeall.analyzeall")` instead of `ID.analyzeall`; it's assigned at the top of the plugin code. The convention for IDs is "pluginname.localid".